# Access macro not working?

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, module

I created a function in a module:

```
Public Function createTable()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim fld As Field

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef("161-0363")

    Set fld = tdf.CreateField("SKUS", dbText, 30)
    tdf.Fields.Append fld

    Set fld = tdf.CreateField("Count", dbInteger)
    tdf.Fields.Append fld
End Function
```

Then called this function in a macro using "RunCode". But no table is created when I run the macro?
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Macro Design View, you should have it say `RunCode`, then in your `Function Name` it should say `createTable()`

Does the code create a table if you run it without a macro?

EDIT:
Update your code to this then run your macro

```
Public Function createTable()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As Field

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef("161-0363")

    Set fld = tdf.CreateField("SKUS", dbText, 30)
    tdf.Fields.Append fld

    Set fld = tdf.CreateField("Count", dbInteger)
    tdf.Fields.Append fld

    db.TableDefs.Append tdf
    db.TableDefs.Refresh
End Function
```

I just tested the above code and it created the table.  You needed to add the last lines of code to get it to work.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. How would you run this without a macro?

Comment: Oh Thanks a bunch that worked, yea that makes sense you would have to append the table. Also what does adding DAO to the declarations do? I tried without and it still worked?

Comment: glad it worked, i used DAO to make things clearer but it isn't necessary

Comment: Pedantic clarification, bluefeet: adding `DAO` isn't necessary *unless* there's also a reference to ADO (and it still isn't necessary *unless* the ADO reference is higher in the list than the DAO reference).

Comment: ...it's necessary should the database ever at some point get an ADO reference added that is above the DAO reference. In other words, put it in for all of your code as insurance against breaking it in the future when somebody adds an ADO reference. I think it also makes the code execute marginally faster, but variable declarations are not exactly a performance drain...

Comment: "How do you run this without a macro?" Hit Ctrl-G on the keyboard, and in the Immediate Window at the bottom, type `?createTable()` and hit ENTER. I don't know why this is defined as a function, since it returns nothing, but it's a function, so that's how you call it.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton it is a Function because you can't call a Sub from a macro.  It throws an error if you try to do that.  If you want it a Sub, then you need a function to call it.

Comment: If it's a function, it should have a return value, even if it's not used for anything. In the rare cases where I have to write a function for calling from a macro, I always define the return type as Boolean and return True at the end. It's just good practice. It may not be required, but functions that return nothing are not really functions at all, except in name.

Comment: I put the DAO qualifier on all the DAO data types, even the ones that don't overlap with ADO, simply because it makes for clearer code. Also, it means I don't have to know a damned thing about ADO, which I don't use in the first place.